# Without Administrator Privileges Launching Desktop Application in a logged in User context with Administrator Privileges

Tags: c#, .net, security, winapi, uac

I wanted to run local desktop applications which are installed in Program Files and Program File (x86) folders only, the application should run with administrator privileges as logged in user context. I have googled and got to know some.

**Required as per my idea:-**

1. File Explorer GUI with Socket Client
2. A Service
3. Local Application Launching Executable with Socket Server ( console application)

**Note: The communication between File Explorer will happen using socket client and server. The service will launch the local application server in system context.**

Imagine that File Explorer, Service and Application Launching server are installed. 
Using File explorer the app will be selected and selected application information will be sent to the server. The server will do check on the requested path whether it is from trusted path or not.

If it is from trusted path, the server will get handle from "winlogon.exe" and get the handle to the access token, then duplicate the access token and adjust its privileges (default system privilege will be there and i don't want that as system will have full privileges) then use CreateProcessAsUser to launch the application.

Once launched bring the UI to the foreground. The application need to be run in user context with administrator privileges.

**My questions are stated below:-**

1. To achieve this do i need to enable the interactive process in the
   service ?
2. If interactive is necessary, the communication between the
   user and local server is happening using socket and user do not
   interact with service directly, just wanted to know whether am i
   following the Microsoft safety measures as stated in below
   documentation or am i breaching it?.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services
3. Do we have any other way to launch an application with admin
   privileges in logged on user context without actual administrator privilege ?

The targeted OS is Windows 10 1803 and 1809.

Comment: I don't really understand what a server would be used for in your context. Do you want to lanuch an application on the users computer, based on some interaction with the server (i.e. using a webpage)? Can you be a bit more clear about what you want to happen?

Comment: Interactive services don't do what you think they do. That all ended with Vista and session 0 isolation of services.

Comment: Yes I want to run some desktop application based on user interaction with Local socket server(console application), which would be running in background with system account context @PMF

Comment: @KeViN [Each app that requires the administrator access token must prompt for consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works#uac-process-and-interactions). You can call [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch) with "runas" operation to run the target app as admin privilege. The launcher app doesn't require admin privilege. Like this: `ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe", NULL, NULL, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for the tools `psexec` or `paexec` (they're mostly identical, the major difference being that the later is open-source).

These tools allow you to start a process as another user and/or on another computer. This should work from a service as well.